# while testing model in ruby with minitest i'm saving data in def setup and i'm getting line what this line means

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

what this line means after running

```
Not sending to list. <Development mode>
```

> RAILS_ENV=test rails test test/models

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

# test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end
   setup do
    @user = User.new(email: "pikabhu@qq.com", password: "1234567890")
    @user.save
    end

    test "email is must" do
      @user1 = users(:two)
      assert_not @user1.save, "Email required for user"
      end

    test "profile must create" do
      assert @user.profile.present?, "profile is not created while creating user"
    end

    test "candidate must create" do
      assert @user.candidate.present?, "candidate is not created while creating user"
    end
```

=========================================

This is what I'm getting

> RAILS_ENV=test rails test test/models
>
> Run options: --seed 5508

**Running:**

```
Not sending to list. <Development mode>
.Not sending to list. <Development mode>
.Not sending to list. <Development mode>
.Not sending to list. <Development mode>
.Not sending to list. <Development mode>
.Not sending to list. <Development mode>
```

..

> Finished in 4.576713s, 1.5295 runs/s, 1.5295 assertions/s.
> 7 runs, 7 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Comment: Which line of code generates these lines? Are you sure you don't put this in stdout somewhere in your code?

Comment: yeh i got the solution , actually i have this line in my code which meant to don't send mail in development mode so as i'm testing the model it showing me this line